# Combination of elements with a defined constraint (edited)

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, programming

I'm trying to program a solution for this problem. So let's say I have a finite set elements ${X_{1},X_{2} , ..., X_{N}}$. To each element $X_{i}$ from the set, there is some assigned value, let's say $k_{i}$ and length $l_{i}$.
I want to find, for example, the top n, $1 \leqslant n \leqslant N$ , combination of elements such that the sum of the assigned values is maximized and that the length doesn't exceed some constant K.

So I can just find all combinations and calculate the sum of the values and choose the top n. But for a large set and constraint, this would be a very inefficient way. Do you guys have a more efficient way of tackling this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in the "knapsack problem" of operations research. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

Sort $X_1,...,X_N$ based on their weights $k_i$. Then you can find combinations that fit the criteria with maximum number of elements. Any subsets of these combinations obviously also fit the bill. That should offer a considerable speedup.

Comment: sorry, I just edited a question, there is a second constraint with a length for each element

Comment: It's literally the knapsack problem then that awkward linked.